# Freelancer's method of setting up azure systems

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am setting up some simple Azure services for a company that does not have an IT team yet. My three goals are

1. The company has to use the Azure portal minimally. The owner is not tech-oriented.
2. The company can add billing information for the subscription themselves without having to give me all that information.
3. I can eventually transfer ownership of the azure entity (directory? tenant?) to an IT team.

I cannot find the answer online because all the documentation is oriented towards an IT that works for the company as opposed to freelancer. I am currently using my personal Microsoft account but am able to get a company Microsoft account if needed via their parent organization (which does have IT). Using my personal account, I've created a new tenant then switched to that directory. In that directory I've attempted to add a subscription but it switches me back to my default directory. If I switch to the new directory again, I get the error "In order to view your eligible offers, please click here to switch your directory to {my account}.onmicrosoft.com"

I would appreciate an in-depth answer as I am not familiar with the administration side of Azure.

Comment: Is your personal account free trial account or pay as you go ?

Comment: It is pay as you go, but I don't want their services mixed with my personal projects.

Comment: I had same problem.. I created a new Tenant, also created a new Subscription under my account for the client. Then I transfer this subscription to new tenant.. It took like 20 mins so just wait. After a while you can transfer ownership using the same method.